# Update single column with Multiple values SQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
id | name | address| code
--------------------------
1  |   ABC| XYZ    |
2  |   DEF| GHI    |
3  |   JKL| MNO    |
4  |   PQR| STU    |
5  |   VWW| QWE    |
```

I need to update the table and insert values in the column code.
I have the  code

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    code= 
   CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'ASD'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'FGH'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'JKL'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'QWE'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'BAR'
   END
WHERE  id IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Can I perform this in a single query as i have to update 14,000 records.
Thanks!

Comment: you have already posted single query, what do you wants to do ?

Comment: it is already single query

Comment: If I have to update 14,000 columns rather than 5 column, do i need to write a long query. what if we can insert any value in "code". It need not to be specified. to be more specific we can update code with 'ASD' or 'FGH' either on id = 1

Comment: @RahulBhagwat : And first of all you tell us that which `rdbms` are you using?

Comment: @Wanderer :  I am using MYSQL rdbms

Comment: @RahulBhagwat Please remove the other tags since it is confusing.

Comment: i think this what you need UPDATE mytable
SET    code= 
CASE round(rand()*5)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'ASD'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'FGH'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'JKL'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'QWE'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'BAR'
    WHEN 0 THEN 'ASD'
END

Answer (score 0):

Use UPDATE query in below format :

```
UPDATE mytable SET code = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'ASD'
                               WHEN id = 2 THEN 'FGH'
                               WHEN id = 3 THEN 'JKL' 
                               WHEN id = 4 THEN 'QWE'
                               WHEN id = 5 THEN 'BAR' ELSE code END
```

Comment: What is the difference between your query and the OP's?

Comment: @Wanderer, no WHERE statement

Comment: @Mansoor, bad idea... what will be set for record with id = 6?

Comment: OP needs to update 14, 000 rows and update it using a `CASE` expression is really a painful job.

Answer (score 0):

i think this what you need

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    code= 
CASE round(rand()*5)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'ASD'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'FGH'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'JKL'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'QWE'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'BAR'
    WHEN 0 THEN 'ASD'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `CSV` file with columns `id` and `code`. And then import that `CSV` to a temp table.

**Query**

```
create temporary table tempTable (id int, code varchar(255));

load data infile 'csv_file_path' into table tempTable ;
```

Then update your table using a `JOIN` with temp table.

```
update myTable t1
join tempTable t2
on t1.id = t2.id
set t1.code = t2.code;
```

After that, just drop the temp table.

```
drop temporary table if exists tempTable;
```